# How can I create this special sequence?

Tags: r, sequence, seq, rep

I would like to create the following vector sequence.

```
0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

My thought was to create `0` first with `rep()` but not sure how to add the `1:4`.

Comment: If one of the responses answered your question,  please click the check-mark to accept the answer.  You might take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rep()` to create a sequence that has `n + 1` of each value:

```
n <- 4
myseq <- rep(seq_len(n), seq_len(n) + 1)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

Then you can use `diff()` to find the elements you want. You need to append a `1` to the end of the `diff()` output, since you always want the last value.

```
c(diff(myseq), 1)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Then you just need to multiply the original sequence with the `diff()` output.

```
myseq <- myseq * c(diff(myseq), 1)
myseq
# [1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a diagonal matrix, take the upper triangle, and remove the first element:

```
d <- diag(0:4)
d[upper.tri(d, TRUE)][-1L]
# [1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

If you prefer a one-liner that makes no global assignments, wrap it up in a function:

```
(function() { d <- diag(0:4); d[upper.tri(d, TRUE)][-1L] })()
# [1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

And for code golf purposes, here's another variation using `d` from above:

```
d[!lower.tri(d)][-1L]
# [1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

Answer (score 5):

`rep` and `rbind` up to their old tricks:

```
rep(rbind(0,1:4),rbind(1:4,1))
#[1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

This essentially creates 2 matrices, one for the value, and one for how many times the value is repeated. `rep` does not care if an input is a matrix, as it will just flatten it back to a vector going down each column in order.

```
rbind(0,1:4)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    2    3    4

rbind(1:4,1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unlist(lapply(1:4, function(i) c(rep(0,i),i)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# the sequence
s = 1:4

# create zeros vector
vec = rep(0, sum(s+1))

# assign the sequence to the corresponding position in the zeros vector
vec[cumsum(s+1)] <- s

vec
# [1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```

---

Or to be more succinct, use `replace`:

```
replace(rep(0, sum(s+1)), cumsum(s+1), s)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 4
```